# Strings difference in Java

Tags: java

/**Why is the output false here on comparing cat and dog references??**/

```
public class Test {

     public static void main(String [] main) {

         final String cat = "length: 10";

         final String dog = "length: " + "10";

        System.out.println("Animals are equal :" + cat == dog);

  }

}
```

Comment: can u people atleast provide me a link to that question.

Comment: Yeah, updated. Take a look.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `System.out.println("Animals are equal :" + (cat == dog));` prints true.

Comment: But some are more equal than others :)

Comment: ah my bad. @SotiriosDelimanoliswas right. damn

Comment: @RomainHippeau Four legs good, two legs _better_!  Four legs good, two legs _better_!  Four legs .......